# How to setup a blockchain network with TLS in peers and orderers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

This page in hyperledger documentation shows which enviroment variable should be used to setup peers and orderers: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/enable_tls.html

in peers:

> CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED = true CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE = fully qualified
>   path of the server certificate CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE = fully
>   qualified path of the server private key CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE =
>   fully qualified path of the CA chain file
>   CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED = true
>   CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES = fully qualified path of the CA
>   chain file CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE = fully qualified path of the
>   client certificate CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE = fully qualified path
>   of the client key

and in the orderer:

> ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED = true ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY =
>   fully qualified path of the file that contains the server private key
>   ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE = fully qualified path of the file
>   that contains the server certificate ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS =
>   fully qualified path of the file that contains the certificate chain
>   of the CA that issued TLS server certificate
>   ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED = true
>   ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS = fully qualified path of the file
>   that contains the certificate chain of the CA that issued TLS server
>   certificate

The problem is, I don't know which certificate from the crypto materal I should use in those env variables.

And I don't know each env variable should be used when, for example, when creating the channel, a command that requires the following arguments for a tls connection:

> --cafile Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
>   --certfile Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
>   --keyfile Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint

1) Which certificate from the crypto material generated I should use in while starting the peer and orderer?

2) Which certificate should I pass as arguments in the peer channel create command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm doing (and works for me):

Orderer:

```
          (....)
          - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
          - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
          - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
          - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
        command: orderer
        volumes:
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.example.com/orderers/orderer.org1.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        (....)
```

Peer:

```
   (....)
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        command: peer node start
        volumes:
            - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
  (....)
```

CLI:

```
(....)          
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
(....)
```

Create channel command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.org1.example.com:7050 -c channelname --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/org1.example.com/orderers/orderer.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem -f ./channel-artifacts/channelname.tx
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Could as well provide an example command to join this channel? Currently I face a strange problem. I'm able to succesfully create the channel, but not able to join it... FORBIDDEN

Comment: @FedorPetrov peer channel join -b channelname.block

Comment: It works now but it didn't work for me earlier:) However, the problem had somehow to do with the fact, that I forgot to set CouchDB environmental variables for my peer nodes. Without these variables set, the peer was able to create channel but not to join it. The error message had to do with the unknown authority but not with couchdb.