# How to use the node SDK to invoke a chaincode with TLS enabled?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I setup the network with the enviroment variables as described in this answer: [How to setup a blockchain network with TLS in peers and orderers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152469/how-to-setup-a-blockchain-network-with-tls-in-peers-and-orderers/54168494#54168494)

And used the following code to load load the certs used in the CLI:

```
let serverCert = fs.readFileSync('./tlsca.com-cert.pem');
let clientCert = fs.readFileSync('./server.crt');
let clientKey = fs.readFileSync('./server.key');

fabricClient.setTlsClientCertAndKey(Buffer.from(clientCert).toString(), Buffer.from(clientKey).toString());

let peer = fabricClient.newPeer(peerEndpoint, {
    'pem': Buffer.from(serverCert).toString()
});
peerList.push(peer);
channel.addPeer(peer);

channel.addOrderer(fabricClient.newOrderer(ordererEndpoint, {
    'pem': Buffer.from(serverCert).toString()
}));
```

The chaincode did work with the command `peer invoke` but it doesn't work with the node sdk, given the following error:

```
routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this method:

```
var Client = require('fabric-client');
var Channel = require('fabric-client').Channel;
var client = Client.loadFromConfig("config/configfile.yaml");

async function invokeTransaction(channelName, mspId, chaincodeId, fcn, args){
    var channel = new Channel(channelName, client);
    let tx_id = client.newTransactionID(true);
    let chaincodeInvokeRequest = {
        targets: client.getPeersForOrg(mspId),
        chaincodeId: chaincodeId,
        txId: tx_id,
        fcn: fcn,
        args: args
    }
    var result = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(chaincodeInvokeRequest, 60000);
    if(result[0][0].response.status != 200){
        return result[0][0].response;
    }
    let transactionRequest = {
        txId: tx_id,
        proposal: result[1],
        proposalResponses: result[0]
    }
    var response = await channel.sendTransaction(transactionRequest, 60000);
    return response;
}
```

You can check a little tutorial to create the config profile file [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html).Dont forget to set the client header in your configfile.yaml

Comment: I setup a network.yml and used your code to invoke the chaincode, but I got the error: No identity has been assigned to this client.

Comment: Add this section in to the configfile.yaml, after version and before channel:  `client:    organization: [organization]`         (For this example, is **Org1** or **Org2**).